What is the effect of pausing (or disabling) the Google Contacts app
I use phone(s) with the stock Google Contacts app.
Enabling Extreme Battery Saver on Pixel causes the Contacts app to pause (by default).
If I enable Extreme Battery Saver on Pixel, and let it pause the Contacts app, does it pause automatic sync of Contacts?
Could this help save battery usage?
I am considering changing Extreme Battery Saver settings to allow the Contacts app.  Could this increase battery usage?
It does not have an immediate visible effect on the toggle at Settings > Passwords > my-account@gmail.com (Google) > Account sync > Contacts.
I can also manually pause the Contacts app "for the rest of the day".  Or I can disable it.  I assume these have the same effect.
My usual habit is to use the Contacts app, because it allows me to view a subset of contacts  who e.g. have phone numbers.  AFAICS, the Google Phone app has decided to show all contacts across all Google Accounts, including those without phone numbers, and cannot be reconfigured.

The Contacts app is not required to sync contacts.  If I completely disable (or remove) the Google Contacts app, Android continues to sync new contacts with contacts.google.com.
There is no reason to believe that pausing the Google Contacts app will reduce the frequency of Google Contacts sync.
The official docs agree that the Contacts app is an optional extra, not a requirement for sync:

Sync Google Contacts with your mobile device or computer
Your Google contacts sync to your Android device when you sign in. Changes to your contacts will automatically sync to keep them backed up and up to date. If multiple Google Accounts are signed in to the same device, Google contacts from all accounts will sync to the device.
Important: If you use a work or school Google Account, download the Contacts app to get all contact details, like job titles.


The above link was found via Gemini.  Gemini responds and publishes a completely wrong answer.  The trick is that when you ask the question yourself (only), it waits a few seconds and then decorates the answer with search references and warnings.
